# scrlttr2: How to left-justify the firsthead at right page edge?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, scrlttr2, justification

Assumed we have this **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{babel}

\newkomavar{fromplace}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1}
\setkomavar{fromplace}{12345 Cologne}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \raggedleft
        {\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces{\usekomavar{fromname}\\\usekomavar{fromaddress}\\\usekomavar{fromplace}}}\\
    }
}

% \KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft} <--- To move the date to the left edge

\begin{document}

    \begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

        \opening{Hello Bob,}

        \closing{Best wishes}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

How can I left-justify the `firsthead` at the right page edge? The `date` is also left-justified, so it should work anyhow. :-)

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a table in the `\firsthead`. I use array to get access to fixed width `w`-column, but you may also use a `p`-column. Also, you may calculate the width of the column using `\dimexpr` instead of hard coding the width:

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{babel, array}

\newkomavar{fromplace}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1}
\setkomavar{fromplace}{12345 Cologne}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{wl{13cm}l}
           &\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces{\usekomavar{fromname}}\\
           &\usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
           &\usekomavar{fromplace}\\
         \end{tabular*}
    }


% \KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft} <--- To move the date to the left edge

\begin{document}

    \begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

        \opening{Hello Bob,}

        \closing{Best wishes}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2:**

You may also modify your code. Just use a narrower `\parbox`, left align its content, and right align the `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{babel}

\newkomavar{fromplace}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1}
\setkomavar{fromplace}{12345 Cologne}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \raggedleft\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{%           %% Move the `\parbox` to the right margin and limit its width to the content
        \raggedright                              %% Left align the content
        {\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces{\usekomavar{fromname}\\\usekomavar{fromaddress}\\\usekomavar{fromplace}}}\\
    }
}

% \KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft} <--- To move the date to the left edge

\begin{document}

    \begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

        \opening{Hello Bob,}

        \closing{Best wishes}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```